# How ternary operator works?

Tags: java, ternary-operator

In codewars I have completed a kata using for loop with 15 lines of code, some other person has completed it with just 7 lines. Could anybody explain the code?

```
public class CamelCase {
    public static String cAmEl(final String yourName) {
        final int length = yourName.length();
        final StringBuilder cAmEl = new StringBuilder(length);
        boolean upper = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++, upper ^= true) {
            final char c = yourName.charAt(i);
            cAmEl.append(upper ? toUpperCase(c) : toLowerCase(c));
        }
        return cAmEl.toString();
    }
}
```

The code converts every alternate character of a string to uppercase (starting with an uppercase character). For example: `test` becomes `TeSt`.

I am unable to understand this part

```
cAmEl.append(upper ? toUpperCase(c) : toLowerCase(c));
```

Comment: its an if-else, if upper then toUpperCase() else toLowerCase()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ternary Operator - JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163713/ternary-operator-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ternary Operators Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219695/ternary-operators-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you don't understand is a ternary.
Ternary contains of three parts.
part one: Condition

```
upper
```

part two: True statement

```
toUpperCase(c)
```

part three: False Statement

```
toLowerCase(c)
```

As you can see in for statement upper will be XOR to literal value true.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++, upper ^= true)
```

So in each iterate of the for statement value of upper variable will be reverse, so true statement and false statement in ternary will be called.

Answer (score 4):

```
cAmEl.append(upper ? toUpperCase(c) : toLowerCase(c))
```

This line appends the next character to a `StringBuilder`. It appends `toUpperCase(c)` if upper is `true` and toLowerCase(c) if upper case is `false`. It uses the ternary operator, which is similar to :

```
if (upper)
    cAmEl.append (toUpperCase(c));
else
    cAmEl.append (toLowerCase(c));
```

Since upper alternates between true and false (that's what the XOR operator does here - `upper ^= true`), this means that the output characters will alternate between upper case and lower case, as required.

Comment: While it is true that `bool ? foo : bar` is ternary operator (just like `++` is unary and `a * b` is binary) just because Java doesn't have more ternary operators people are using "ternary" as if it is was proper name of this operator. But since we are not guaranteed that in future Java will not add more ternary operators, it is better to call it by its proper name which is "[conditional operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)".

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but you can do it in one (quite long) line of code:

```
return yourName.length() <= 1 ? yourName.toUpperCase() : "" + Character.toUpperCase(yourName.charAt(0)) + Character.toLowerCase(yourName.charAt(1)) + cAmEl(yourName.substring(2));
```

or splitting it up a bit:

```
return yourName.length() <= 1 ? yourName.toUpperCase() : 
    "" + Character.toUpperCase(yourName.charAt(0)) +  
         Character.toLowerCase(yourName.charAt(1)) + 
         cAmEl(yourName.substring(2));
```