# what does the instruction Math.floor do

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out what this statement means and what the variable `larg` contains:

```
int larg;
larg = ((larg % 8 != 0) ? (int) (Math.floor(larg / 8.0) + 1) * 8 : larg);
```

Comment: That rounds up to the nearest `8`. The `Math.floor` is spurious unless `larg` is a floating point type.

Comment: Note that `?` and `:` together makes the ternary operator (which is an if-statement in disguise).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219695/ternary-operators-java for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part

```
(larg % 8 != 0)
```

asks if larg does not divide without a remainder by 8.  If so

```
(int) (Math.floor(larg / 8.0) + 1) * 8
```

is executed which divides larg by 8, rounds down to discard the remainder and adds one, and then multiplies back by 8.  This means find the next multiplum of 8 larger than `larg`.

This is put in a ternary operator `...? ... : ...` which is an if-statement.  So

```
larg =((larg % 8 != 0) ? (int) (Math.floor(larg / 8.0) + 1) * 8 : larg);
```

means:  "*If larg is not a multiple of 8, round up to the next multiple of 8, otherwise set it to itself*".   Another way to put it (as division of an integer by an integer discards the fraction)

```
if (larg % 8 != 0) {
    larg = ((larg / 8) + 1) * 8;
}
```

This code was most likely written by a semi-experienced programmer, who preferred a one-liner instead of the three-line `if`-statement.  A more experienced programmer would know that readability is more important than keeping it on one line, so a future reader like you would understand it instead of having to ask here.

Comment: Since the intention is to round up to the next multiple of 8, an even more intuitive way of writing it would be `larg = Math.ceil(larg / 8.0) * 8;` without any conditional logic at all.

Comment: In your last example, you should mention that `larg` must also be integral for that to work. Although I now notice that the OP has updated the question to include the `int` declaration.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem using doubles to do integer arithmetic is rarely the most efficient.