# i want to understand the code that i show for java return statement

Tags: java, ternary-operator

This question I found on my class work and I got confused

I haven't tried anything

```java
public static String evenOrOdd(int num) {
    return num%2==0?"Even":"Odd";
}
```

The code runs fine; I just wanna know how it works.

Comment: Search for "ternary operator"

Comment: Which construct in that statement don't you understand? The modulo (`%`) operator or the ternary (`? :`) operator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ternary Operators Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219695/ternary-operators-java)

Answer (score 2):

It is basically an `if else`statement.

If the condition is true, it will return the first option. If not (if it is false), it will return the second:

```
num%2==0?"Even":"Odd";
```

If `num%2==0`then it is `Even`. If not, then it is `Odd`.

It is a one-liner to:

```
if(num%2==0) return "Even";
else return "Odd";
```

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operator is just like `if else` statement.

```
if (num % 2 == 0) {
 return "Even";
} else {
 return "Odd";
}
```

If the part before `?` mark is `true` then you will get the result before `:` .
If `false` then after `:`

Answer (score 1):

look for  ternary operator
above code is short form of

```
public static String evenOrOdd(int num) {
    if(num%2==0){
      return "even";
    }else{
      return "Odd";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called a ternary operator and its logic works as follows

```
a question ? positive answer : negative answer
```

or, using more formal terms

```
boolean expression ? return value for true : return value for false
```

So, your question is about `num % 2 == 0` which means if a remainder for the `num` divided by two is zero. If this is the case – it's an even number, if not – it's an odd number, and that is why a corresponding string value is returned.